# Localizate many straight black lines using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new in Matlab and currently working on a project on barcode.

How can I locate the barcode in the product with image processing using Matlab?

Is there any clue on what I can research on?

Comment: Have you tried to look on the other sides of the box? :) Sorry, couldn't hold it.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8999080/1134940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might help:

[Barcode Recognition Using Live Video Acquisition](http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/imaq/demoimaqsl_barcoderecognition.html)

[Barcode Recognition](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/vision/vipbarcoderecognition.html)

[Image Processing for Barcode Recognition](http://www.softwarepractice.org/wiki/Image_Processing_for_Barcode_Recognition)

Comment: Thanks for the info!!
But this example seem easy because the background is white!!
Therefore the barcode is easily been extracted!

I currently dealing with lots of texts and colors